# mathematically assessment quantification of a person

Tags: functions, systems-of-equations, percentages, scoring-algorithm

I want to do assessment of persons by interviewing them for a specific job. Let us say there are 5 skills in which i want to evaluate them, different skills are not equally important. And for each skill I will grade them A, B, C or D, let us say 100%, 75%, 50% and 25%.

At the end I want to get the individual's score in percentage.. like person X scored 80%, Y scored 90% and so on.

I cannot work out what will be its mathematical equation?

Comment: Have you assigned percentage scores to A, B, C, D?

Comment: let us say 100%, 75%, 50% and 25%

Comment: Is each skill equally important? Or do you want to assign a weight to it?

Comment: yes you are right different skills are not equally important. Should i make their relative weights or should i make weight for each skill w.r.t to the total of all skills?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way is to do it is like so:

Each sub-score is assigned a percentage (so they are all based on the same denominator). And assign weights to each. The weights can all be set to $1$ if you want all sub-scores to carry equal weight.

So for sub-score $A$ (for task $A$), we assign weight $w_A$, etc.

Let's stick to five tasks as per your requirement.

The total score $S$ as a percentage will then be:

$S = \frac{w_AA +w_BB + w_CC +  w_DD + w_EE }{w_A + w_B +w_C + w_D +w_E}$

Comment: why we need "400" in denominator?

Comment: @alt-rose Sorry, I made an error. I've edited it.

Comment: I've edited to cover five tasks as per your question.

Comment: Little confusing in the symbols used. In your equation what is "WA" and what is "A"? and when I give score for a skill X.. let us say the score in skill X is 'C', which is 50%.. then where do I plug-in this value in your equation?

Comment: any specific requirements for the sum of all weights in the denominator?

Comment: In my answer A, B, C, D, E are sub-scores for five individual tasks (or individual skills). In place of them you write the percentage score for each task. They are not grades (this might be the source of your confusion). Basically you multiply the percentage score for a task by the weight assigned to that task. Do this for each task. Add these up. Divide the total by the total of all the weights. No specific requirement for the weights, they can be any real positive number except zero (in which case that task doesn't count anymore).

Comment: To avoid skewing the results, it might be better to keep the weights as small as possible and fairly close to one another (to keep all the tasks meaningful). I would probably assign positive weights with a maximum of $1$ for each task. There's no hard and fast rule here though. But note that if you assign a weight of $1$ to one task and $100$ to another, you're pretty much disregarding the first completely.